# Как закрыть div jade

Tags: node.js, express, jade

Использую шаблонизатор Jade.

Пишу в Jade файле

```
div.classname1 YOUR TEXT 1
div.classneme2 YOUR TEXT 2
```

Или так

```
div(class='classname1') YOUR TEXT 1
div(class='classname2') YOUR TEXT 2
```

В результате выполнения получаю

```
<div class="classname1">YOUR TEXT 1<div class="classname2">YOUR TEXT 2</div></div>
```

Т.е. второй блок "вкладывается" в первый. Вопрос в том: как сделать, чтобы они не "вкладывались" друг в друга. Пробовал много различных конструкций реализации, но ни что не помогло.

Подсобите советом пожалуйста, ковыряю уже целый день. Что-то упускаю...

Comment: Может у вас проблемы с переводами строк?) Просто данный шаблон не должен выдавать вложенных тегов ни при каких обстоятельствах

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, опубликуйте, пожалуйста, свой комментарий как ответ (только в виде утверждения, а не вопроса).

Comment: @user227219, удалите, пожалуйста, своё «спасибо» и примите ответ Дмитрия (когда тот его опубликует) как верный; также можете поставить этому ответу «плюс».

Comment: @Arhad, зачем? Вопрос вызван опечаткой и, согласно правилам ru.SO, должен быть закрыт. (Ну и в идеале мире - удален.)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, какая ж это опечатка, когда среда неверный перенос ставит? От пользователя-то тут ничего не зависит

Comment: @Grundy, вы действительно считаете, что PhpStorm не умеет ставить правильные переносы строк? На мой взгляд - проблема в пользователе и в текущей постановке она нелокализуема (только хрустальный шар покажет, что пошло не так).

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, я просто не представляю как можно ввести неверный перенос строк :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, как вариант, по умолчанию ставится `\n`, а плагину надо `\r\n` или наоборот. И это явно не похоже на опечатку

Comment: @Grundy, ок, пусть будет не опечатка, а не воспроизводимая проблема. Вопрос все равно стоит сжечь. Или будете пытаться меня убедить, что проблема воспроизводится?